# I'm pulling data from an API through a C# program, but program's performance isn't convincing me

Tags: c#, performance, api, parallel-processing

As title says: I'm extracting data from an API through a C# program (in this case Shopify's API). First of at all, Shopify's API got the following limitation: it uses the [leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) algorithm for handle incoming requests, where **its bucket size is 40 request**, and the **rate of leak is 2 request per second**. So in case the bucket is full, and a new request hits the API, the API itself will respond with a HTTP 429 error message *(too many requests)*. *You can check more about this in Shopify's documentation: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/api-call-limit.*

I'm pulling some data from Shopify by hitting their API, and actually the amount of data is kind of small (like 80-90k of order's transactions), but due to API's limitation, is kind of tricky/hard achieve this on the smallest amount of time possible. So basically what my program does is burst like 40 calls to the Shopify's API, I wait for them, then sleep the program for a couple of seconds (10 seconds), and the burst the next 40 calls. Due to I'm hitting the next burst without waiting the corresponding time for avoid HTTP 429 responses, I implemented the retry pattern for retry HTTP calls that fails because some transient error (like HTTP 429, 503, and so on), so I'm ensure I'm trying my best to not retrieve partial results.

So that's what my program does; **I pulled 85k transactions in 11 hours** (which I feel this is pretty bad), but I'm trying to see where else I can improve for reduce the hours of processing. I know that there's a bottleneck on the Shopify's API, but this is something out of my scope... do you think guys that there's some technique/approach for improve data pulling from an API? I'd like to hear your opinions/thoughts about this. I'm totally open to any suggestion! Also, I'd be so thankful.

Check the code snippet below for see one of my program's functions that shows the logic explained above. I'd also thank any review on the code; like, is it the performance offered by `AsParallel` method from `ParallelEnumerable` class good enough for the situation that I'm handling?

```
public void BulkInsertOrdersEvents(List<long> orders, IPersistence persistence)
{
    if (orders != null && orders.Any())
    {
        return;
    }

    short ordersPerBurst = 40;
    int totalOrders = orders.Count;
    int ordersProcessed = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (ordersProcessed >= totalOrders)
        {
            break;
        }

        var ordersForProcess = orders.Skip(ordersProcessed).Take(ordersPerBurst);
        var orderEventsBag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

        ordersForProcess.AsParallel().ForAll((orderId) =>
        {
            var httpCallParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            httpCallParameters.Add("orderId", orderId);

            Console.WriteLine("Started processing the order {0}", orderId);

            int pages = CalculatePages(ShopifyEntity.OrderEvent, httpCallParameters);

            if (pages == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            string getOrderEventsEndpoint = string.Format(ShopifyApiEndpoints.GET_ORDER_EVENTS_BY_ORDER_ID, orderId) + $"?limit=250"; ;

            Parallel.For(1, pages + 1, (index) =>
            {
                //Create HTTP client for call Shopify API
                var httpClient = GetHttpClient();
                var httpHeaders = GetHttpHeaders();

                //Call Shopify API for return order transactions
                string orderEvents = httpClient.Get(getOrderEventsEndpoint + "&page=" + index, httpHeaders);

                Console.WriteLine("Obtained page {0} of Events from Order {1}", index, orderId);

                //Put the order's events for current page into concurrent bag
                orderEventsBag.Add(orderEvents);
            });


            Console.WriteLine("Finished processing the order {0}", orderId);
        });

        Dictionary<string, object> saveParameters = null;

        if (persistence.GetType().Name.Equals(typeof(BlobPersistence).Name))
        {
            string fileName = string.Format(ShopifyApiConstants.ORDER_EVENTS_FILE_NAME_TEMPLATE, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
            saveParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"fileName", fileName}
                };
        }

        //Merge all events pages into a single JSON and store it.
        var orderEventsJson = JsonHelper.MergeJsons(orderEventsBag.ToArray());
        persistence.Save(orderEventsJson, saveParameters);

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        ordersProcessed += ordersPerBurst;
    }

}
```

I missed to mention that I'm also storing these results on Azure blob storage; but this isn't a problem at all! Where my program is taking so much time it's when pulling the data from Shopify.

Thanks so much, guys!

Comment: If i count correctly you did request above the limit. `85,000 / 11hrs / 60 min / 60 seconds = 2.14 request per seconds` You poll rate is maxed. You need to pay for Shopify Plus to double that limit.

Comment: There is probably some refactoring you could do, but it looks like the API throttle effectively lets you make 2 calls/second, which works out to 7200 calls per hour. Nothing you do on your end can change that. What exactly are you looking to improve?

Comment: you already know your bottleneck is on the API limit side. Doesnt matter how efficient your own algorithm is you will still end up with the same result. So what are you looking to improve?